# Error code: 500 - Website not loading

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have moved my website from one host to another.  I have transferred the domain, uploaded all files and also the database.

I am now receiving this error when trying to load the page:

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://lingeriemodel.co.za/web/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

I have tried looking in cPanel error log for an error, but there are no errors showing?

What could be causing this?

Web Info:
Symphony
[Link to website](http://lingeriemodel.co.za/web/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the program running your website isn't displaying the full error message. Perhaps there is more information in your webserver error log (is that what you saw from cPanel?), if not you'll need to talk to whomever developed your website to figure out how to increase logging or error reporting.